# populate table view with prototype cells

Tags: xcode, tableview

I have this scene:

[image]

I added one simple "table view" and next +1 into "prototype cells":

[image]

informacao.h

```
NSMutableArray *arrCursos;
```

informacao.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Informações";
    arrCursos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrCursos addObject:@"[G] - Odontologia"];
    [arrCursos addObject:@"[P/LT] - Odontologia"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrCursos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cursosCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrCursos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I don't know why my table view is empty, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Now, there are a few places you should check. First is whether the table view data source has been connected to the view controller. Check if the number of rows data source method is called and whether it is returning the expected number of rows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d", arrCursos.count); 
    return [arrCursos count];
}
```

Second is to check whether you have specified the cell identifier `cursosCell` in your storyboard.

[image]

Comment: tks...but the problem was missing delegate and datasource

Comment: @user1535906 yeah, the data source is what I mentioned in the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was missing delegate and datasource